# htaccess - Wordpress multiple languages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a online store and support multiple languages for my store. I had used htaccess to control the url on my store. Details

```
domain.com/product-name
domain.com/de/product-name
domain.com/jp/product-name
```

Now, I have installed wordpress in /wordpress/ folder and config htaccess to it displays:

```
domain.com/features/post-title
```

Today, I have installed the wpml.org to wordpress can support multiple languages but the URL does not work with this.

```
domain.com/features/post-title (english)
domain.com/features/de/post-title (German)
domain.com/features/jp/post-title (Japanese)
```

**My questions is, how to URLs display like above urls.**

Finally, this is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [E=VAR1:$1,QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^features/?$ index.php?main_page=features[QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^features/.*$ index.php?main_page=features[QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^features\?(.*)$ index.php?main_page=features?$1 [QSA,L]
```